# Does logback comes as bundled with springboot. dont what is wrong here . i just need to create a file with only a type of logs like error or debug

Tags: spring-boot, logback

```
<!-- Appender for the main log file -->
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/application.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/application.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Appender for the warning log file -->
<appender name="WARNING_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <file>logs/warning.log</file>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>logs/warning.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
    </rollingPolicy>
    <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
        <level>WARN</level>
    </filter>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>

<!-- Root logger -->
<root level="INFO">
    <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    <appender-ref ref="WARNING_FILE"/>
</root>
```

This is the logback xml file i am using to save only warning type of logs(sample).
This is not getting executed at all. I was hoping i should get some warning if i dont have directory access.

Answer (score 0):

Logback is indeed coupled with Spring Boot by default, and it's usually the default logging framework used by Spring Boot applications. However, to ensure that Logback is correctly configured make sure that your `logback.xml` file is located in the correct directory, it should be in `src/main/resources`.

Please read this: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.logging

In the provided configuration, the root logger is set to INFO level, which means it will log messages at INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL levels. If you only want to log WARN, you should set the root logger to that level.

One of the benefits of spring boot is that you can configure it using `application.yaml` file like this:

```
logging:
  level:
    root: WARN
```

Comment: Sure i will test it and update